# Map the upper group to the column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following (ordered) dataframe `df`:

```
Level    ID
5        A
8        DD
8        DA
8        AC
5        B
8        BA
8        BB
8        BC
8        BD
```

The logic is that the Level 5 , which stands above the level 8 has to get mapped to it, that means:

```
Level    ID   Upper_ID
5        A       A
8        DD      A
8        DA      A
8        AC      A
5        B       B
8        BA      B
8        BB      B
8        BC      B
8        BD      B
```

How can I achieve this? I want to map the "upper group ID" to it. So everytime a new `5` in the Level column occurs, that menas this is the new  upper group for the Level 8 until the next 5 occurs.

Comment: Can you explain more `The logic is that the Level 5 , which stands above the level 8 has to get mapped to it, that means`

Comment: `df['Upper_ID'] = df['ID'].where(df['Level'].eq(5)).ffill()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to propagate the value when there is a change of Level to a lower level, identify the position of the change with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)+[`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html), then select the top values with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['Upper_ID'] = df['ID'].where(df['Level'].diff(-1).lt(0)).ffill()
```

Or, just matching a `5`:

```
df['Upper_ID'] = df['ID'].where(df['Level'].eq(5)).ffill()
```

Output:

```
   Level  ID Upper_ID
0      5   A        A
1      8  AA        A
2      8  AB        A
3      8  AC        A
4      5   B        B
5      8  BA        B
6      8  BB        B
7      8  BC        B
8      8  BD        B
```

Intermediates (first approach):

```
   Level  ID Upper_ID  diff  lt(0) where ffill
0      5   A        A  -3.0   True     A     A
1      8  AA        A   0.0  False   NaN     A
2      8  AB        A   0.0  False   NaN     A
3      8  AC        A   3.0  False   NaN     A
4      5   B        B  -3.0   True     B     B
5      8  BA        B   0.0  False   NaN     B
6      8  BB        B   0.0  False   NaN     B
7      8  BC        B   0.0  False   NaN     B
8      8  BD        B   NaN  False   NaN     B
```

Comment: @PV8 thanks for the clarification, do you only have 5 and 8?

Comment: Yes, there are only 5 and 8, its already cleaned

Comment: Then the less generic `df['ID'].where(df['Level'].eq(5)).ffill()` is enough ;)